# Why is my Animation Not Working in Roblox Studio

Tags: animation, lua, roblox

So I followed this one DevKing tutorial to make an animation and for some reason I cant get it  to work, because I got this error: `attempt to index nil with 'Humanoid'`

This is my code:

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local char = player.Character
local Hum = char.Humanoid
local ArmAnim = script.ArmAnim
local ArmTrack = Hum:LoadAnimation(ArmAnim)
ArmTrack:Play()
```

I have already tried rereading all of my code and looking back at the video but I cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: SifflePiffle, where is this LocalScript located? Is it in a Tool, or in StarterPlayerScripts, or somewhere else?

Comment: its in the  starter player scripts

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work just fine, but you have a timing issue in your code. Based on the comments in the question, since this LocalScript is in [StarterPlayerScripts](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/StarterPlayerScripts), this script will fire as soon as a player joins. But, when a player first joins the server, their character is not immediately spawned into the world. So there is a short time period where `player.Character` is nil.

So to fix this issue, you need to wait until the character is loaded into the world.

You can do this in a few different ways.

1. **Move this LocalScript into [StarterCharacterScripts](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/StarterCharacterScripts).** This will change when the script fires to after the character is loaded into the world.

or

2. **Alter your LocalScript to wait for the Humanoid to exist.**

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local char = player.Character

-- if the player hasn't loaded yet, wait for the character to spawn into the world
if char == nil then
    player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
    char = player.Character
end

local hum = char.Humanoid
local ArmAnim = script.ArmAnim
local ArmTrack = hum:LoadAnimation(ArmAnim)
ArmTrack:Play()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate the help a lot!